# Select value from Datasource transport on kendo ComboBox

Tags: symfony, combobox, kendo-ui

I'm using [kendo ComboBox](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox), that uses remote data-source as mentioned in code below :

```
$("#myinput").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "...",
    autoBind: false,
    height: 300,
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "{{ path('my_search_ajax') }}"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And to select a value from the combobox usually we use the select methode as mentioned [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#methods-select).

```
<input id="combobox" />
<script>
$("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
  dataSource: [ "Apples", "Oranges" ]
});

var combobox = $("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox");
combobox.select(0);
combobox.trigger("change");
</script>
```

But this did not work for me maybe because I'm using a remote datasource so I have tried the [search](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#methods-search) methode and did not work also, I still can't set a value selected in the combobox.

So maybe guys I'm missing something like configuration or additional method, I'm not sure actually. Hope you help me with this.

Comment: Are there any errors being reported in the console window? Where in your code are you attempting to trigger the `change` event?It would help if you had a reproducible example, JSFiddle/Dojo.

Comment: The way you wrote your question, it's impossible for us to help you since we don't know what your are expecting nor what your error is.

Comment: @Sandman sorry for the late answer but the console shows me no errors

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf Thanks for your feedback I have edited my question please take a look.

Comment: Is there any data in the combobox?

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to wait until your dataSource is loaded. So You need to register [dataBound](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#events-dataBound) event for your comboBox and there select your value.